# TCP Packets Syntax Error

Tags: python-3.x, tcp

I am having issues with a syntax error I can't seem to solve. I am trying to reassemble a tcp packet after a checksum.

```
 def reassemble_tcp_feilds(self):
   self.raw = struct.pack('!HHLLBBH', 
   self.tcp_src, 
   self.tcp_dst, 
   self.tcp_seq, 
   self.tcp_ack_seq, 
   self.tcp_hdr_len, 
   self.tcp_flags , 
   self.tcp_wdw
   )+
   struct.pack("H", 
   self.tcp_chksum
   )+
   struct.pack('!H', 
   self.tcp_urg_ptr
   )
   return
```

The error occurs in the addition of the first struct.pack with the next struct.pack. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can't end a line with an operator, the `+` needs to have something after it, not just a new line. This should work for you, however:

```
def reassemble_tcp_feilds(self):
   self.raw = struct.pack('!HHLLBBH', 
   self.tcp_src, 
   self.tcp_dst, 
   self.tcp_seq, 
   self.tcp_ack_seq, 
   self.tcp_hdr_len, 
   self.tcp_flags , 
   self.tcp_wdw
   )+struct.pack("H", 
   self.tcp_chksum
   )+struct.pack('!H', 
   self.tcp_urg_ptr
   )
   return
```